# Would df.sort_values('A', kind = 'mergesort').sort_index(kind = 'mergesort') be a stable and valid way to sort by index and column?

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I have a Pandas dataframe equivalent to:

```
              'A' 'B'
'i1' 'i2' 'i3'
 1    2   4    3   0
 1    1   2    3   3
 1    1   2    1   0
 1    2   4    0   9
 1    1   2    2   6
 2    1   1    1   8
```

where ix are index columns and 'A', and 'B' are normal columns. I want to make sure that the indexes are strictly ordered and, when indexes are duplicated, then it is ordered by column 'A'

```
              'A' 'B'
'i1' 'i2' 'i3'
 1    1   2    1   0
 1    1   2    2   6
 1    1   2    3   3
 1    2   4    0   9
 1    2   4    3   0
 2    1   1    1   8
```

Would df.sort_values('A', kind = 'mergesort').sort_index(kind = 'mergesort') do it? And if so, would do it in a stable way? or could the .sort_index() operation disrupt the previous .sort_values() operation in such a way that, for the duplicated indexes, the values of 'A' are no longer ordered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you sort by multiple keys, only the last one is guaranteed to be sorted. The others will be sorted within the previous groups. Finally, the non-key columns will remain sorted in the original order in case of a stable sort such as the mergesort.

To answer your question, yes, your method will maintain the original order in case of duplicated keys.